# Probability before a set amount of draws

Tags: probability

I'm trying to write a games program based on "Mexican Loteria". For those unfamiliar with the game it's similar to bingo, the general rules are that:

- You have 54 different symbols that are chosen once.
- The boards are 4x4 with no repeating symbols and no free spaces.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the probability that the entire board is covered (all 16 randomly chosen symbols) are covered before an "n" amount of draws. I've calculated the amount of possible unique cards is equal to 54!/38!. How would I go about calculating the rest of this problem?

Comment: sorry typo, fixed thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are $\binom{54}n$ ways of drawing the $n$ numbers, and $\binom{54-16}{n-16}=\binom{38}{n-16}$ ways of drawing them so they contain the $16$ numbers on the card, so the probability that the board is covered *after* $n$ draws is

$$
\frac{\binom{54}n}{\binom{38}{n-16}}\;.
$$

To get the probability that the board is covered *before* $n$ draws, just subtract $1$ from $n$.